# how many channels does a bayer image have?

Tags: c++, mat, image-conversion

i am working on bayer images. i use basler camera and i get bayerBG8 image from it. in pylon i can directly converted to RGB, but i want to save the bayer image so i need to specify its channels to define a mat file. when i use 1 channel for it i get gray scale image and if i choose more than on channel, images repeated in one frame as shown:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bayer filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter) is a technique to use a single-channel image sensor to receive color image by defining which pixel should represent which color, so a bayer image should have one channel.

Comment: thank you for you response. The pixel format in camera  is on bayer mode so it seems to apply a bayer filter on raw data (am i right?) so shouldn't be a 4 channel image?